# Tableau calculated field : i'm trying to create calculated field in tableau

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api

i'm trying to create calculated field in tableau, my query is below:

```
SUM(IF([Qtr]='2018-Q1' OR [Qtr]='2018-Q2' OR [Qtr]='2018-Q3' OR [Qtr]='2018-Q4')
 THEN FLOAT([Channel Mix]) END) / FLOAT([Revenue])
```

i'm getting error saying cannot **mix agreegate** and **non agreegate** comparison.

Final objective is to divide with revenue column .

Please help

Comment: try attr() function on Channel Mix or Revenue. One of them is an already aggregated field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your numerator is a sum (an aggregation) but your denominator is not. Try dividing by:
 `/ sum(FLOAT([Revenue]))`

Comment: Thanks for the response, however i tired doing it but still i get a same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SUM(IF([Qtr]='2018-Q1' OR [Qtr]='2018-Q2' OR [Qtr]='2018-Q3' OR [Qtr]='2018-Q4') 
 THEN FLOAT([Channel Mix]) END) /SUM(FLOAT([Revenue])
```